# changing svn repository on my local pc

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have a web server on cloud, svn already installed. My question is how to locate it on my local repository, meaning install on my local pc. It is possible? If so, please help me.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is answered in the Subversion manual at http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.migrate

Answer (score 0):

It's actually pretty difficult to understand what you're asking. Are you referring to how to checkout the repository on your local PC? If so you simply need to run an `svn checkout` to retrieve a working repo of the repository.

`svn co https://url/to/repo/trunk`

---

If you're talking about moving your entire repository to your local PC, you're going to have to do an `svnadmin dump > repo.dmp` and then create a new local repository on your local PC. You will then need to run a `svnadmin load /path/to/repo.dmp` to load the contents onto your local repository.